# Draw a exrta line at specific angle in high chart

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

As I given an URL below, In that example, there is option to draw a line when drag by mouse,But I need a button and when click over that, draw a line over graph at 60 degree angle. I am using [highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/demo). 
Visit [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/N6GR9/) `jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/N6GR9/`

Comment: Just like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7m3Mr/ ? As you can see there are buttons, where you can add callbacks (step&stop) when adding an annotation. More on the [github](http://blacklabel.github.io/annotations).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imarinovsk/uca8r27m/).

```
chart.renderer.path
```

is a method you can use for drawing paths in general and a line in this case.